# Debug a Java project which is invoked through a perl script

Tags: java, eclipse, perl, debugging

I am working on a big Java project which is on eclipse. To use the program we need to invoke a perl script in the terminal with the parameters then that script will call the program. In this case how can I debug the program in eclipse?

In summary : perl program invokes java program and I need to debug the Java program in eclipse

Comment: Debug which part of the program -- the Java portion or the Perl portion?

Comment: Java portion. Perl script is already written and it is stable. I am working on Java project.

Comment: NO..This project is already there for a long time and I m just staring  to work on it. my problem is bit similar to this problem http://www.epic-ide.org/tracker/step-through-java-and-perl-code.php. In summary : perl program invokes java program and I need to debug the Java program in eclipse

Comment: I do not know of a solution, but am curious as to why the requirement that the Perl program invoke the Java program? Do they have to communicate somehow? If so, could you instead have them communicate through sockets and thus be able to start up the Java program in Eclipse?

Comment: First, there are different different Java binaries and based on the passed arguments, perl program will do all pre processing on the arguments and then call the appropriate the java binary. Second, In this way we can use  the program as a terminal command. so end user point of view it is very convenient. ( Linux program, No GUI )

Comment: They sound like reasonable requirements. Sorry for not being of much help, but I do wish you much luck. 1+ for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could you do this using [java remote debugging in Eclipse](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html).

Your perl script would have to launch the java app with options to enable remote debugging in the JVM, for example

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=y
```

You then tell Eclipse to connect to that JVM by making a "Remote Java Application" debug configuration that specifies the correct host/port.

Comment: Hi Thanks...I works.. but if the Java version is above or equal to  1.5 then the options should be **-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000**.